# mysqli.reconnect = ON changed connection encoding?

Tags: sql, mysql, character-encoding, reconnect

how to prevent switching the connection encoding by reconnect? Everything of my settings are utf-8, but since I have enabled this function in php.ini of the cli ... I have tested anything ... and when I have a long working script then in any point of the script the connection is switched and I have wrong data. After I have disabled it again, then everything is fine. But why is it so? What kind of settings should I set in my.cfg to prevent this switching of the connection encoding?

Cheers
Nik

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html):

> If you are using the mysql client with auto-reconnect enabled (which is not recommended), it is preferable to use the charset command rather than SET NAMES. For example:

```
 mysql> charset utf8
 Charset changed
```

The charset command issues a SET NAMES statement, and **also changes the default character set that mysql uses when it reconnects after the connection has dropped**. Therefore, issue this:

```
 mysqli_query('charset utf8');
```

Or whatever charset you're using (if other than UTF8). This should fix the problem.